# How do I interpret the linear regression models when significance is lost when interaction term is added

Tags: r, regression, interaction

Can someone kindly help me to interpret a model - `lm(A ~ sqrt(B) + as.factor(C), data =mydata)` which gives a result that B is significantly associated with A (based on the overall regression p-value of $0.04877 \lt 0.05$)?

```
Call:
lm(formula = A ~ sqrt(B) +  as.factor(C), data = mydata)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-146.495  -69.309   -0.163   62.497  144.305 

Coefficients:
                               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                     92.8062    16.0901   5.768 3.13e-08 ***
sqrt(B)                         1.1386     0.5052   2.254   0.0253 *  
as.factor(C)1                   -8.3650    14.1517  -0.591   0.5551    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 76.67 on 194 degrees of freedom
  (239 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.03066,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.02067 
F-statistic: 3.068 on 2 and 194 DF,  p-value: 0.04877
```

But when I add an interaction term between B and C, B is no longer significantly associated with A $(p=0.1039):$

```
Call:
lm(formula = A ~ sqrt(B) * as.factor(C), data = mydata)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-143.166  -68.855   -1.526   63.332  145.317 

Coefficients:
                                    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                         85.7015    25.0446  3.422 0.000759 ***
sqrt(B)                             1.3873     0.8405   1.651 0.100442    
as.factor(C)1                       5.2475    39.3584   0.133 0.894075    
sqrt(B):as.factor(C)1              -0.3904    1.0530   -0.371 0.711215    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 76.85 on 193 degrees of freedom
  (239 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.03135,   Adjusted R-squared:  0.01629 
F-statistic: 2.082 on 3 and 193 DF,  p-value: 0.1039
```

**Why did the association between B and A in the first model vanish when the interaction was added?** Please help me interpret these two models

Comment: Take a look at https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interactions-main-effects-not-significant/ I would also recommend plotting your data somehow (like in the link) to see what's going on

Comment: The link in the comment above doesn't answer the question.

Comment: +1.  It would be more accurate to characterize this as an *increase in p-value* rather than a "vanishing" of an association.  The significance threshold of 0.05 (which you seem implicitly to be using) is not a sharp demarcation between the existence and non-existence of an effect.

Answer (score 1):

This has happened to me a few times due to multicollinearity; your interaction term ( sqrt(B):as.factor(C) ) might be highly correlated with your main effect ( sqrt(B) ), so including both of them renders them non-significant.

Answer (score 1):

Without the interaction term in the model, we can fairly intuitively interpret the meaning of the coefficient for `sqrt(B)`: it's the expected change in `A` for every 1-unit change of `sqrt(B)`.

With the interaction term in the model, the lower-order coefficient `sqrt(B)` has a very specific meaning. By including the interaction term, you're building in the model assumption that the slope of `sqrt(B)` changes depending on the value of `as.factor(C)`. The coefficient for `sqrt(B)` in your output represents the slope *when `as.factor(C)` is not equal to 1*. The interaction term is the extent to which the slope changes when `as.factor(C)` is equal to 1.

In your case, it doesn't appear that the slopes of `sqrt(B)` and `as.factor(C)` depend on the values of each other. I wouldn't consider the change in coefficient/p-value from one model to the next to be particularly meaningful. It also depends on the reference level of `as.factor(C)`. I don't know what the values of `C` are, but if you refit the model with something like `as.factor(C, levels = c(1, 0))` you would have a different reference level for `as.factor(C)` and would probably see a different coefficient for `sqrt(B)`, which would be the estimate of the slope when `as.factor(C)` *is* equal to 1.